# R str_replace_all Does Not Seem to Be Working Correctly

Tags: r, str-replace

The following line of code does not appear to be working correctly for me:

```
df$Combined2<-str_replace_all(df$Combined,"0[+]","")
```

The string cell that I am questioning and trying to break apart follows:

```
 0+0+0+0+0+0+0+0+0+0+0+0+0+Ultimate+0+0+0+0+0+0+0+Multiple 8x10+0+0+0+3x5+0+0+0+0+0+0
```

What I would like for the end results would be something like the following:

```
Ultimate+Multiple 8x10+3x5
```

But it looks like the following:

```
Ultimate+Multiple 8x13x5+0
```

I cannot figure out what I am doing incorrectly here. It looks like it sort of combined the 8x10 & 3x5 fields, but they truly are supposed to be different and not combined.

Actually - I might have just figured this out because I am removing the 0+s (or 0[+] and that it why it is sort of combining the fields. Even though I solved it I still think it is worthy of sharing with the group - I hope you agree.

Comment: if you solved it, you should post your solution as an answer (as soon as you're allowed to; there will be some kind of waiting period)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `gsub`:

```
gsub('(?<!\\d)0\\+?|[+]0', '', vec, perl = T)

[1] "Ultimate+Multiple 8x10+3x5"
```

data

```
vec = '0+0+0+0+0+0+0+0+0+0+0+0+0+Ultimate+0+0+0+0+0+0+0+Multiple 8x10+0+0+0+3x5+0+0+0+0+0+0'
```